# Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found (yii2 basic)

Tags: php, yii2

I downloaded the yii2-jui in this link

[yii2-jui](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui)

After that I put it under yiisoft folder

yiisoft\yii2-jui

when I run my application it gives me this error

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found

How can I fixed this.where should I put the yii2-jui folder ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Stop creating duplicate questions.

And you do not just download something and copy it in a folder. Use composer to install it. the Yii2 that you copied is just a shell, you have to use composer to install the rest of it. Composer does more then just copy the files it creates an autoloader that tells yii where everything is.

Comment: This is not a valid answer, comments on the type of question may be indicated once a detailed answer has been given on how to resolve a doubt. It is important to understand that there are those who are starting in stack overflow and guiding them to ask questions of better quality is important.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the problem when I ran 
`sudo composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui` "*" 
ONLY IN FOLDER `basic`, where are `web`, `yii`, `models` and etc.

Answer (score 2):

Insert this in the view:

```
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
```

The best way is: run: php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui "*" in your project

Answer (score 2):

insert code:

```
  'yiisoft/yii2-jui' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-jui',
    'version' => '2.0.2',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/jui' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-jui',
    ),
  ),
```

in yiisoft/extensions.php file

Comment: Thanks! I've got something screwy going on with Composer, and I'd forgotten I could force it like this :)